# What is the difference between conditional probability and a stochastic kernel?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

I have visited various [sites](https://infostructuralist.wordpress.com/2013/03/17/stochastic-kernels-vs-conditional-probability-distributions/) which claim a difference between stochastic kernels and conditional probability. However, I have read a [paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1674619?class=pdf) which treats them the same, and the Wikipedia page on [transition matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) actually lists a matrix full of conditional probabilities. The page linking to it claims that a Markov-kernel ([stochastic-kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel), or probability-kernel) is simply an element of this transition matrix.

> This is a contradiction in literature, and I would like some clarity on
>   the issue. What is the difference between a stochastic kernel and a
>   conditional probability statement?

It's possible they differ in generality alone, where the stochastic kernel is a specific case of conditional probability, but I haven't found any references on this.

Comment: The term "conditional probability" is general and context free, while "stochastic kernels" is used only when discussing stochastic processes. A stochastic kernel is a specific type of conditional probability (density) statement, while a conditional probability can be a statement that has nothing to do with stochastic processes.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I know it has been a long time, but if you write your comment out as an answer, I can accept it, and people googling the same question will be able to see the answer without looking in the comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term *conditional probability*, is free of context, while *stochastic kernel* is used only when discussing stochastic processes.

A stochastic kernel is a specific type of probability density statement, while a conditional probability can be a statement which has nothing to do with stochastic processes.

*The answer is curtsy of a comment by @Lee David Chung Lin.*